# How to know which view is pushed to some view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Here is my question:

I have 3 different `UIViewControllers`;

The first is A, the second is B, and the third is C.

A has a push segue to B and then I'm doing some stuff in the `ViewDidLoad` method.
C also has a segue to B and then i=I need to do other stuff in the `ViewDidLoad` method.

Is there any way to know which `UIViewController` A or C has pushed to B?

Comment: ok ill be more specific.
i have a user profile view which has few UITextField. in the profile i have a button that push to search view where the user can choose which country and city he lives. after the user choosed i need to change to values in the first view (A) so i need to know which view is pushed to A because

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a property in the .h file in class B like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *viewControllerName;
```

And in the `-prepareForSegue:` method in class A and class C, you could set the `viewControllerName` property to equal class A's name or class C's name.
Then a simple if-else check in class B's `viewDidLoad` should help you load it accordingly.

Example B.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface B : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic) NSString *view;

@end
```

Example C.m or A.m

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        B *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.view = @"C"; // Change to A if this is in A.m
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i pretty new..
can you write some example code?

Comment: I'd go with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes . In your navigation Stack you will be able to trace it as which view had pushed the present view

NSArray *arr=[self.navigationController ViewControllers];

IOf you print his array you will get a backtrace of all the viewCOntroller in the navigation Stack

Comment: not all the ViewControllers have a NavigationController

Comment: After what I read from your comment , I am guessing you need to pass some data from one ViewController to the next is it correct??...any ways evenif our are presenting or dismissing a controller you can figure out its parentViewControlller by using self.presentingViewController.parentVIewCOntroller

Answer (score 1):

In the `.m` of class B, lets call it, `ViewController_B.m`

```
#import "ViewController_A.h"
#import "ViewController_C.h"

//...

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    NSArray *arrViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    if (arrViewControllers.count <= 1) { //not needed but just incase, maybe?
        NSLog(@"No parent");
        return;
    }

    id vcCurrent = arrViewControllers[arrViewControllers.count-2];
    if ([vcCurrent isKindOfClass:[ViewController_A class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Pushed by A");
        //Do class A specific things

    }
    else if ([vcCurrent isKindOfClass:[ViewController_C class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Pushed by C");
        //Do class C specific things

    }
}
```

---

I have, however, never done it this way.
I would keep a parameter in class B to identify what logic to load it with. <sup>(as suggested by @WyattMufson in his [answer above/below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24941342/2857130))</sup>